# Postgresql - set columns based on jsonb columns with the same name

Tags: postgresql

My table has a jsonb field `report` that has fields I want to copy to columns I already have in the same table. I don't want to create new records. I just want to update each row. I want to do something like this:

`UPDATE project SET col1 = report->>'col1', col2 = report->>'col2', col3 = report->>'col3';`

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I get this error ```** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42804 (datatype_mismatch) column "col1" is of type double precision but expression is of type text```. col1, col2, and col3 are all floats and even the jsonb values are floats, but for some reason executing the above query recognizes the jsonb values as text.